# Debug height HTML, jQuery masonry

Tags: jquery, html, debugging, height

I'm using jQuery masonry and facing a problem, the margin between boxes (vertically) sometimes varies.
The only way to set the margin correct is using the browser console to reload masonry

```
jQuery( ... ).masonry( 'reload' );
```

Something is causing an height change after initializing masonry and I cant find it (static content only, no scripts involved)..

edit:
This issue is related with external fonts being loaded from remote destinations.

Thanks!

Comment: Without jsfiddle, online sandbox, it's impossible to check your problem with Chrome's devtools or other. There surely is "something" causing your problem - but where can one look at it and check the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer, after searching I found out that this issue is described in the Masonry website https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/3

Solution: use WebFont Loader and reload masonry after the font loaded callback

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the benefit of other SO users, questions may be better answered in the open, I think.

Are you using fonts from fonts.com, typekit.com or google.com/webfonts? If you test your page with the standard fonts and then it all works correctly, it may be that your webfonts are loading very late, which prohibits Masonry from working out the correct vertical dimension of each brick, which then messes up the vertical layout. If you say it looks correct after reloading, it could mean that by then all content and external code (texts, images, fonts, scripts, etc.) has been loaded so that after that reload everything looks as expected.